# Does Firefox Leak My Real IP Through Safe Browsing Service?

Tags: firefox, privacy

I am using Firefox. I found some settings in about:config starting with:

`browser.safebrowsing.provider.google....`

I know I can disable some of them, however, it's a long list to handle.

Does Firefox send my real IP to Google through this service?

Answer (score 1):

#### Does Firefox send my real IP to Google through this service?

Yes, as the IP address is needed to provide the service. Full explanation follows.

> **How Safe Browsing works in Firefox**
>
> The main part of the Safe Browsing system is the one that watches for
> bad URLs as you're browsing. Browsing protection currently protects
> users from:
>
> - malware sites,
> - deceptive sites (including phishing and social engineering sites), and
> - sites hosting potentially unwanted software.
>
> If a Firefox user attempts to visit one of these sites, a warning page
> will show up instead.
>
> ...
>
> The second part of the Safe Browsing system protects users against
> malicious downloads. It was launched in 2011, implemented in Firefox
> 31 on Windows and enabled in Firefox 39 on Mac and Linux.

Source: [How Safe Browsing works in Firefox](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/how-safe-browsing-works-in-firefox/)

Further Reading:

- [Google Online Security Blog: How Hash-Based Safe Browsing Works in Google Chrome](https://security.googleblog.com/2022/08/how-hash-based-safe-browsing-works-in.html)
- [Security/Safe Browsing - MozillaWiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Safe_Browsing)

---

#### What information is sent to Mozilla or its partners when Phishing and Malware Protection is enabled?

> There are two times when Firefox will communicate with Mozilla’s
> partners while using Phishing and Malware Protection for sites. The
> first is during the regular updates to the lists of reporting phishing
> and malware sites. No information about you or the sites you visit is
> communicated during list updates. The second is in the event that you
> encounter a reported phishing or malware site. Before blocking the
> site, Firefox will request a double-check to ensure that the reported
> site has not been removed from the list since your last update. This
> request does not include the complete address of the visited site, it
> only contains partial information derived from the address.
>
> In addition to the regular list updates mentioned above, when using
> Malware Protection to protect downloaded files, Firefox may
> communicate with Mozilla's partners to verify the safety of certain
> executable files. **In these cases, Firefox will submit some information
> about the file, including the name, origin, size and a cryptographic
> hash of the contents, to the Google Safe Browsing service which helps
> Firefox determine whether or not the file should be blocked.**
>
> The [Mozilla Privacy Policy](https://www.mozilla.org/privacy-policy.html) describes what data Firefox and Mozilla
> each receive and how it's handled. The [Google Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) explains
> how Google handles collected data.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [How does built-in Phishing and Malware Protection work?](https://www.mozilla.org/privacy-policy.html)

Comment: …but it needs to know your IP address to know where to send the answer back to… no?

Comment: That's why I don't feel 100% confident about my privacy. I couldn't find 100% reliable info about that specific issue. I am using FoxyProxy, however, I don't know for sure if this addon can also route traffic sent to Google Safe Browsing or is only limited to proxying the current request used to bring the web page ressoucres.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, answer updated.

Comment: AFA - you can't communicate at all on the internet if the site you're connecting to doesn't know your IP address. It's like complaining to the council about rubbish being dumped in your street… without telling them where you live. Part of the whole 'privacy policy' bit is that they don't use this information to track you.